# SQL IIF syntax for incorporating into query

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif

I have looked it up but only get the basic syntax not how to incorporate with the rest of my SQL query.

Do I do this;

```
UPDATE survey
SET IIF ((survey.azimuth+180)>360, survey.azimuth=(survey.azimuth-180), survey.azimuth=(survey.azimuth+180)
;
```

Or this?

```
UPDATE survey
IIF ((survey.azimuth+180)>360, SET survey.azimuth=(survey.azimuth-180), SET survey.azimuth=(survey.azimuth+180)
;
```

Does CASE not work in Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both will not work. `CASE` is not supported in Access. you use this.

```
UPDATE 
    survey
SET 
    azimuth = IIF ((azimuth + 180) > 360, 
                   (azimuth - 180), 
                   (azimuth + 180));
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark it as answer if this has helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE survey
SET azimuth = IIF (azimuth + 180 > 360, azimuth - 180, azimuth + 180)
```